# Logical Operator Exercise in Codecademy: hit a wall

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

What is missing in the following code?

I keep trying variations and am at that point where I'm trying illogical modifications simply for lack of better ideas.  Does the problem lie in the function syntax?  Best I understand the variables are global, and both SHOULD read as TRUE.  Depending on how I structure the function I can get a read out of TRUE AND FALSE, or false, but, if I understand Logical Operator syntax correctly, only one outcome should output to true - when both variables are true.  Hence, as I set them to true, I'm a bit mystified WHY the readout is getting False.![enter image description here][1]

```
// Declare your variables here!
var foodHere=true;
var hungry=true;

var eat = function() 
{
if (hungry&&foodHere) 
{
      console.log ("True.");
}
else
{
      console.log("False.");
  }
};
```

//Error message reads: It looks like your function doesn't return false when hungry is false.

I'd post the image but apparently my reputation is lacking.

Comment: Replace `console.log('false');` with `return false`

Comment: `It looks like your function doesn't return false when hungry is false`; your function doesn't ***return*** anything. Try adding a return statement; e.g. `return false;` or `return true;` at the right points in your code.

Answer (score 2):

CodeAcademy wants you to **return** a boolean value, whereas you're just logging a "True" or "False" string to the console. Change it to something like:

```
var eat = function(){
   return (hungry && foodHere);
}
```

or in your case:

```
var eat = function() 
{
    if (hungry&&foodHere) 
    {
          return true;
    }
    else
    {
          return false;
    }
};
```

See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NPZk8/1/).